# Apache htaccess exclude specific URL from 301-redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

On a apache system i added a redirect from the old server to the new one with this .htaccess:

```
redirect 301 / http://www.new-domain.com/redirect.php?q=
```

But i want to exclude this redirect for this URL:

```
http://domain.com/index.php/admin/
```

Every request to the old admin-area having this part in the URL "/index.php/admin" shall remain on the old server and not being redirected to the new one.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mod_rewrite` rule for that instead of `Redirect` that doesn't allow regex:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^index\.php/admin http://www.new-domain.com/redirect.php?q=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive inside an [`If`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#if)

```
<If %{REQUEST_URI} != "/index.php/admin/">
    Redirect ...
</If>
```